# How to know text is Arabic or in Urdu

Tags: java, android, regex, arabic, urdu

I want to  know  is text contain any letter in Urdu or Arabic..using this condition which produce false results when special characters comes.what is right way to do it .any library or what is right regex for this ?

```
   if (cap.replaceAll("\\s+", "").matches("[A-Za-z]+")
                    || cap.replaceAll("\\s+", "").matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")) {
                Log.d("isUrdu", "false");
                caption.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                caption.setTextSize(16);

            } else {
                Log.d("isUrdu", "True");
             /*   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {*/
                    caption.setTypeface(typeface);
                    caption.setTextSize(20);

         /*       }*/
            }
```

Comment: I think you have to convert character to UTF then compare it with Urdu and Arabic character code.

Comment: Try `if (cap.matches("(?s).*[\\p{Arabic}\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70-\\uFEFF].*")) { /*YES, it is either Arabic or Urdu*/ }`. To only check for Urdu, use `"(?s).*[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70-\\uFEFF].*"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Wikipedia *Urdu alphabet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu_alphabet), it includes the following Unicode ranges:

```
U+0600 to U+06FF
U+0750 to U+077F
U+FB50 to U+FDFF
U+FE70 to U+FEFF
```

To match an Arabic letter, you may use a `\p{InArabic}` Unicode property class.

So, you may use

```
if (cap.matches("(?s).*[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70‌​-\\uFEFF].*"))
{
    /*There is an Urdu character*/
} 
else if (cap.matches("(?s).*\\p{InArabic}.*"))
{  
    /* The string contains an Arabic character */ 
}
else { /*No Arabic nor Urdu chars detected */ }
```

Note that `(?s)` enables the `DOTALL` modifier so that `.` could match linebreak symbols, too.

For better performance with `matches`, you may use reverse classes instead of the first `.*`: `"(?s)[^\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70‌​-\\uFEFF]*[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70‌​-\\uFEFF].*"` and `"(?s)\\P{InArabic}*\\p{InArabic}.*"` respectively.

Note you may also use shorter `"[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70‌​-\\uFEFF]"` and `"\\p{InArabic}"` patterns with `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: This is perfect solution for my problem thank you very much

Comment: on cap.matches("(?s).*\\p{Arabic}.*") andriod stuido saying its unknown class

Comment: That means you may use either `\\p{IsArabic}` or `\\p{InArabic}`, please check and let know. Android uses ICU regex library, and it is a bit different from the Java `java.util.regex`.

Comment: Does it also work if text comes from a text or xml file or a database ?

Comment: @MindRoasterMir Regex is used to search for matches in strings, so it is unaware of the source, it just expects a plain text. BTW, use more efficient `"(?s)[^\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70‌​-\\uFEFF]*[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70‌​-\\uFEFF].*"` and `"(?s)\\P{InArabic}*\\p{InArabic}.*"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do without Regex here, all you need is to find what Arabic and Urdu UTF Character range is and then check if the entered text matches the range.

Comment: I think your answer a misleading and based on false information. Urdu and Arabic alphabet dont have same unicode values. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir that wasn't the gist of my answer though, it's actually irrelevant to the question which language he will use, he needs to find the UTF range for the languages he is checking for which can be found on the net, modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this here you can get whether the text is Arabic or not

`var arregex = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
 var test = arregex.test(text);
 return test;`